# Adding dev server to App-Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

My android app is backed by an App-Engine server. All good. Now I need to have a dev/staging server that I can use for testing. So I go with the obvious: create two App-Engine projects: one for production, one for development. Part of the process as you know is to add credentials to each project. The problem I am running into is that I cannot register my android app with both projects because the app fingerprint can only be used in one project. So how do I add a dev project when I need credentials for, say, OAuth?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different signing key for the two different versions of the app.  You should be able to then register the app with each as it is the combination of the app package name and the signing key fingerprint which is used for the OAuth credentials.

Comment: where am I to find that different signing key? I thought they were unique over the app? Would this approach impose a limit on the number of servers I can have? Such as dev, staging, and production?

Comment: The signing key I'm referring to is for the Android app.  You need the signing key's fingerprint along with the Android app package name to create an app-engine (or any GCP, Firebase project) credentials for the Android app.